# Weird Microsoft Word Text Styling

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a Microsoft Word file that was fine, and for some reason, the text is highly condensed now. The text is the Normal style and I checked the spacing on the style and it is regular spacing. I have no idea what could be wrong. Any ideas? Thanks!!

[image: weird word style]

File - MediaFire: http://www.mediafire.com/?ozp6529rbkkzk4h

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! It seems opening the file in Open XML 2.0 SDK Productivity Reflection tool was corrupting the file somehow. Don't open the files in the tool and Word at the same time!!

Comment: Generally, it's a bad idea to open a data file of any sort in two programs at once, unless you _know_ that the file is being opened 'safely' (e.g., in read-only mode, or in transaction mode for databases).